# Batch Rename in Fish shell

Tags: linux, fish, batch-rename

I get 15 or 20 files every week with random names that include several symbols such as `!`,`'` etc. Plus there is `space`. So I need to replace `space` with `_`, and any other symbols to nothing before I can pass them to another script. I use `thunar` for the job now, but I'll very much like to automate it in the script. I'm using `fish` shell.

Comment: Do you have to worry about name collisions?  For example, could you ever have something like `'''a_b.ext` and `''''a b.ext` that the script would attempt to rename to `a_b.ext`?

Comment: No. In 4 months I never found a single one that'd create name collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I find an old tool called `rename`. It did the trick without using `sed` or any complex command.

http://rename.sourceforge.net/